# Can't loop through list in JavaScript with Spring WebSockets

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I am using WebSockets to continuously pass data to my front-end view and I need to loop through an arraylist of stocks with prices. I tried to use stockList.get(i).price which is the correct way of invoking it through Java, but I'm not too sure how to do it via JS.

This is the JS code:

```
var stompClient = null;

    function connect() {

        var socket = new SockJS('/stocks');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            console.log("connected!!!")

            setConnected(true);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/stocks', function(retrieveData) {
                console.log('retrieving...');
                display(retrieveData.body);
            });

        }, function(err) {
            console.log('error occurred while connecting!!!')
        });
    }

    function display(message) {
        if (message) {
            console.log("MESSAGE IS HERE...");
            var stockList = JSON.parse(message).stockTransferList;
            var table = $('<table>');

            for (var i = 1; i <= stockList.length; i++) {
                    var row = $('<tr>').text(stockList[i].price)
                    table.append(row);
            }
            $("#stockBody").append(table);
      }
```

This is the Java code:

```
@MessageMapping("/stocks")
@SendTo("/topic/stocks")
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 3000)
public void retrieveData() throws Exception {

    List<UserDetails> principals = getAllPrincipals();

    for (UserDetails u : principals) { 
        
        User user = userService.findByUsername(u.getUsername());
        
        List<Stock> stocks = stockService.getDefaultStocks(user);
        
        StockTransfer stockTransfer = new StockTransfer(stocks);
        
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(DESTINATION, stockTransfer);
    }
}
```

Stock Transfer:

```
public class StockTransfer implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7685954595695834497L;

List<Stock> stockTransferList = new ArrayList<Stock>();

public StockTransfer(List<Stock> stockTransferList) {
    this.stockTransferList = stockTransferList;
}
```

- Stock class is the class provided from Yahoo Finance. I am passing the list into a serializable class, StockTransfer

CONSOLE ERROR:

```
stomp.js:130 <<< MESSAGE
destination:/topic/stocks
content-type:application/json
subscription:sub-0
message-id:uax8ea34-0
content-length:34153

{"stockTransferList":[{"symbol":"DMTK","name":"DermTech, Inc.","currency":"USD","stockExchange":"NasdaqCM","quote":{"symbol":"DMTK","timeZone":"America/New_York","ask":55.67,"askSize":12,"bid":55.3,"bidSize":8,"price":54.17,"lastTradeSize":null,"lastTradeDateStr":null,"lastTradeTimeStr":null,"lastTradeTime":"2021-02-05T21:00:02.000+0000","open":50.8875,"previousClose":49.24,"dayLow":50.572,"dayHigh":55.73,"yearLow":8.69,"yearHigh":55.736,"priceAvg50":36.8775,"priceAvg200":17.75366,"volume":1952127,"avgVolume":853196,"changeInPercent":10.01,"changeFromAvg50":17.2925,"change":4.93,"changeFromAvg200InPercent":205.12,"changeFromAvg50InPercent":46.89,"changeFromAvg200":36.41634,"changeFromYearHighInPercent":-2.81,"changeFromYearLow":45.48,"changeFromYearLowInPercent":523.36,"changeFromYearHigh":-1.566},"stats":{"symbol":"DMTK","marketCap":1377001344,"sharesFloat":null,"sharesOutstanding":25420000,"sharesOwned":null,"eps":-3.343,"pe":null,"peg":null,"epsEstimateCurrentYear":-1.89,"epsEstimateNextQuarter":null,"epsEstimateNextYear":null,"priceBook":34.306522,"priceSales":null,"bookValuePerShare":1.579,"revenue":null,"oneYearTargetPrice":null,"shortRatio":null,"earningsAnnouncement":"2020-11-10T21:00:00.000+0000","roe":0,"ebitda":null},"dividend":{"symbol":"DMTK","payDate":null,"exDate":null,"annualYield":null,"annualYieldPercent":null},"history":[{"symbol":"DMTK","date":"2020-02-29T16:00:00.000+0000","open":12.630000,"low":8.690000,"high":16.950001,"close":11.250000,"adjClose":11.250000,"volume":1546100},{"symbol":"DMTK","date":"2020-03-31T16:00:00.000+0000","open":10.800000,"low":10.035000,"high":14.400000,"close":13.750000,"adjClose":13.750000,"volume":670300},{"symbol":"DMTK","date":"2020-04-30T16:00:00.000+0000","open":13.750000,"low":11.250000,"high":15.750000,"close":12.400000,"adjClose":12.400000,"volume":1075700},{"symbol":"DMTK","date":"2020-05-31T16:00:00.000+0000","open":12.780000,"low":11.560000,"high":16.794001,"close":13.230000,"adjClose":13.230000,"volume":4039000},{"symbol":"DMTK","date":"2020-06-30T16:00:00.000+0000","open":13.200000,"low":9.640000,"high":14.730000,"close":10.590000,"adjClose":10.590000,"volume":2468800},{"symbol":"DMTK","date":"2020-07-31T16:00:00.000+0000","open":10.730000,"low":10.250000,"high":13.840000,"close":11.770000,"adjClose":11.770000,"volume":2386200},{"symbol":"DMTK","date":"2020-08-31T16:00:00.000+0000","open":11.650000,"low":9.851000,"high":12.000000,"close":11.950000,"adjClose":11.950000,"volume":2915000},{"symbol":"DMTK","date":"2020-09-30T16:00:00.000+0000","open":12.090000,"low":11.000000,"high":13.350000,"close":12.760000,"adjClose":12.760000,"volume":1981500},{"symbol":"DMTK","date":"2020-10-31T16:00:00.000+0000","open":12.880000,"low":11.470000,"high":14.500000,"close":12.380000,"adjClose":12.380000,"volume":3060400},{"symbol":"DMTK","date":"2020-11-30T16:00:00.000+0000","open":12.600000,"low":11.250000,"high":37.369999,"close":32.439999,"adjClose":32.439999,"volume":18481500},{"symbol":"DMTK","date":"2020-12-31T16:00:00.000+0000","open":32.299999,"low":28.000000,"high":47.259998,"close":40.980000,"adjClose":40.980000,"volume":25170100},{"symbol":"DMTK","date":"2021-01-31T16:00:00.000+0000","open":42.650002,"low":39.900002,"high":55.736000,"close":54.169998,"adjClose":54.169998,"volume":5890100},{"symbol":"DMTK","date":"2021-02-04T16:00:00.000+0000","open":50.887501,"low":50.571999,"high":55.730000,"close":54.169998,"adjClose":54.169998,"volume":1952127}],"dividendHistory":[],"splitHistory":[],"valid":true},{"symbol":"ARKK","name":"ARK ETF Trust - ARK Innovation ETF","currency":"USD","stockExchange":"NYSEArca","quote":{"symbol":"ARKK","timeZone":"America/New_York","ask":149.7,"askSize":8,"bid":149.49,"bidSize":14,"price":149.46,"lastTradeSize":null,"lastTradeDateStr":null,"lastTradeTimeStr":null,"lastTradeTime":"2021-02-05T21:00:00.000+0000","open":148.8,"previousClose":148.35,"dayLow":147.42,"dayHigh":149.75,"yearLow":33.0,"yearHigh":149.85,"priceAvg50":138.49907,"priceAvg200":106.48703,"volume":5516391,"avgVolume":5539288,"changeInPercent":0.75,"changeFromAvg50":10.96093,"change":1.11,"changeFromAvg200InPercent":40.36,"changeFromAvg50InPercent":7.91,"changeFromAvg200":42.97297,"changeFromYearHighInPercent":-0.26,"changeFromYearLow":116.46,"changeFromYearLowInPercent":352.91,"changeFromYearHigh":-0.39},"stats":{"symbol":"ARKK","marketCap":null,"sharesFloat":null,"sharesOutstanding":null,"sharesOwned":null,"eps":null,"pe":null,"peg":null,"epsEstimateCurrentYear":null,"epsEstimateNextQuarter":null,"epsEstimateNextYear":null,"priceBook":null,"priceSales":null,"bookValuePerShare":null,"revenue":null,"oneYearTargetPrice":null,"shortRatio":null,"earningsAnnouncement":null,"roe":0,"ebitda":null},"dividend":{"symbol":"ARKK","payDate":null,"exDate":null,"annualYield":null,"annualYieldPercent":null},"history":[{"symbol":"ARKK","date":"2020
stocks:65 retrieving...
stocks:87 MESSAGE IS HERE...
stocks:92 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined
    at display (stocks:92)
    at stocks:66
    at SockJS.onmessage (stomp.js:288)
    at SockJS.REventTarget.dispatchEvent (sockjs-0.3.4.js:84)
    at SockJS._dispatchMessage (sockjs-0.3.4.js:1025)
    at SockJS._didMessage (sockjs-0.3.4.js:1083)
    at WebSocket.that.ws.onmessage (sockjs-0.3.4.js:1215)
display @ stocks:92
(anonymous) @ stocks:66
(anonymous) @ stomp.js:288
REventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs-0.3.4.js:84
SockJS._dispatchMessage @ sockjs-0.3.4.js:1025
SockJS._didMessage @ sockjs-0.3.4.js:1083
that.ws.onmessage @ sockjs-0.3.4.js:1215
stomp.js:130 <<< MESSAGE
destination:/topic/stocks
content-type:application/json
subscription:sub-0
message-id:uax8ea34-1
content-length:34153
```

Getting this error in console when I subscribe to the websocket endpoint to fill the table of stocks:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined
```

Comment: Would you try it as `stockList[i].quote.price`, not `stockList[i].price`?

Comment: I get back: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'quote' of undefined

Comment: Also needs a change in your **for loop**. You have to do it like this: `for (var i = 0; i < stockList.length; i++) {`

Comment: Perfect! You fixed the error. How does <= being changed to < relate to "quote" being undefined? Does it mean 'i' isn't a real value in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `display(message)` function like this:

```js
function display(message) {
    if (message) {
        console.log("MESSAGE IS HERE...");
        var stockList = JSON.parse(message).stockTransferList;
        var table = $('<table>');
        for (var i = 0; i < stockList.length; i++) {
            var row = $('<tr>').text(stockList[i].quote.price)
            table.append(row);
        }   
        $("#stockBody").append(table);
    }
}
```

There are 2 errors in your code:

- The `price` field is under the **quote object** and you need to call it.
- The `stockList` **is an array** and starts at index number 0, but **in your for loop**, you started the index number at 1. *Therefore you need to start this from index number 0.*

**The corrected example version is available at the link:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-brrqlt?file=index.js